# Reverse capture groups with gsub and a block (Ruby)

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to do something like this (without modifying this code):

```
a = '1 and 2'
b = a.gsub(/(\d)/) do |match|
  # Print 2 and 1, reversing the captures matches
end
```

I know I can do a.gsub((\d) and (\d)) and then refer to the matched groups in the block as #$1 and #$2 but I was wondering if it's possible to capture both 1 and 2 in the block without doing this.

Comment: Can I ask you what is the point of reversing the matches?

Comment: I was just wondering if it's possible to be done this way for the sake of it. I know there are more than 1 ways to do it though.

Comment: has my answer was useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible or difficult to do it exactly in that format, but here is something close:

```
"1 and 2".scan(/\d/).reverse.join(" and ")
# => "2 and 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Shorter non gsub solution:

```
a.split(" ").reverse.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish you may use non `gsub` code:

```
a.split(/[^\d]/).select{|s|!s.empty?}.reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do as below :

```
a = '1 and 2'
a.split(" ").reverse.join(" ")
# => "2 and 1"
```